# How to textView.setText from Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to set text to textView from thread. All code is created in oncreate()

something like

```
public TextView pc;

    oncreate(..) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        pc = new TextView(context);
        Thread t =new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                pc.setText("test");
        }};
        t.start();
```

This crashes my app. How can I set text from thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

```
public TextView pc;
Handler handler = new Handler();
oncreate(..) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    pc = new TextView(context);
    Thread t =new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pc.setText("test");
                }
            });
        }
    }};
    t.start();
}
```

But you have another problem. `pc` points to a view that is not part of your hierarchy. You probably want to use `findViewById` with the id of the TextView in your layout.

Comment: We create pc from code. Not in xml. So I cant use findviewbyid?

Comment: If you create pc from code, are you later adding it in to the view hierarchy? Also, why not just call `pc.setText` right after assigning to `pc`?

Comment: because I change it in for (). And for "for" I need new thread or I will see black screen with no elements.

Comment: I understand about the black screen. But `pc` needs to be part of the content hierarchy or it won't show up at all. But did the handler solution resolve the issue of the app crashing? If not, please post the crash info from logcat.

Comment: Handler doesnt work. Just you mean that? `Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
     handler.post(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        pc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wait1);
        pc.setText("TEST"));
}
         }

        }       } );

);`

Comment: Is there a view with id `R.id.wait1` in your content hierarchy? If you're creating the text view in code, be sure to call `setID(R.id.wait1)` before trying to find it.

Comment: I need to access view created before thread, from the thread. How can I do it?

Comment: Okay, let's talk another way. If we take textview from xml, how can we set text from thread? If we use findviewbyid from thread we get blank screen.

Comment: The formula for changing the UI from a background thread is always the same: arrange through a Handler (or some other way) for a Runnable to be executed on the UI thread that will make the necessary calls. I'm wondering if your blank screen problem is due to something else in your code. If you call `setText` from within `onCreate` and then try to _change_ the text by posting a Runnable to a handler, is the screen still blank?

Comment: How can I post runable to a handler? Sorry but I had dificulties with understanding your words in english. Coud you provide example?

Comment: Now I see exception: uncaught handler.

Comment: My code above shows how to post a runnable to a handler. Could you post the code that causes the exception? (To find what code caused the exception, look for the last "caused by..." in the stack trace that was written to logcat.)

Comment: handler=new Handler();

Answer (score 11):

Try [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pc.setText("test");
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you mean? How can I use it?

Comment: With your edits app crashes: could not launch activity Component info

Comment: @POMATu: it's working here. About the stack trace: it's not the first entry that's significant, generally it's the last "caused by..." that matters. The activity couldn't be launched because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Android Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) you can do this easy

> Background Thread
>
> You can change your data model in a background
> thread as long as it is not a collection. Data binding will localize
> each variable / field while evaluating to avoid any concurrency
> issues.

For example

ViewModel.java

```
package somepackage;

public class ViewModel {
    public final ObservableField<String> mTextViewField = new ObservableField<>();

    public void setText(String text) {
        mTextViewField.set(text)
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="somepackage.ViewModel" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.mTextViewField}" />

    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity {

    private ViewModel mViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        MainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main);

        mViewModel = new ViewModel();
        binding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    }

}
```

Now you can address to the mViewModel from any Thread and change text value safely

Answer (score 0):

I know Its too late but this is easy to implement for future developers

Just call this `startCounter()` method.

```
private void startCounter() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        int startTime = 1;
        int endTime = 100;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (startTime <= endTime){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                text.setText(startTime+"");    // text-> TextView
                startTime++;
                }
            });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```