# No error calling textView.setText from non UI-Thread. Why?

Tags: android

I wrote the following Code which basically starts a Thread from which the text of a TextView is changed.

I was expecting an error because I access a TextTiew (UI-element) from another Thread than the main-Thread.

But it works fine. Thought this shouldn't be possible as far as I know.
I don't get it, what am I missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
        tv.setText(Thread.currentThread().getName());

        Thread theThread = new Thread(new aRunnable(tv));
        theThread.start();      
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ARunnable implements Runnable{     
    TextView tv;    
    public ARunnable(TextView tv){
        this.tv = tv;
    }   
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tv.setText(tv.getText()+"----" + Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
    }

}
```

Comment: i assume `aThread` really is `ARunnable`?

Comment: @Bob if you check this poorly formatted piece of code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049882/how-to-textview-settext-from-thread, you see that he does similar to what you do and for him it crashes. This confuses me even more.

Comment: Me too^^
Can anyone run my code to test if it crashes?
I'm running it on a Samsung Note 10.1
The output is main---Thread-1205

Comment: @Simon Bob As I indicated below, Android does not necessarily perform this check consistently. Nonetheless, even if a cross-thread UI call doesn't throw, it is a bad idea. The documentation (linked below) states clearly that the UI classes are not thread-safe. They do not state that Android will always catch you if you do it wrong. It is quite possible that implementation changes in different versions of Android or even - heaven forbid - different devices have changed what UI methods will throw.

Comment: @j__m Thank you for your explanation.
I know it's not the way it meant to be done. I wanted to play around with handlers and just got confused why it doesn't crash without...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) say `Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread.`  They do not say that Android itself contains any code to prevent you from doing so.  It is merely a Bad Idea that could have unintended side effects.

You should call `Activity.runOnUiThread()` to update the UI from other threads.

Comment: Actually, if you try to modify a View outside of the main thread it will throw an exception.

Comment: When I was trying to access an ImageView in an AsyncTask there was a runtime-error saying I'm not allowed to. I thought this would happen for all UI Elements.

Comment: it should be use handler to set the text.

Comment: To my knowledge only the internal class ViewRootImpl contains such a check.  Any UI code that doesn't touch ViewRootImpl will not throw an exception, but it is still not thread-safe.

Comment: see comment of j__m on the question