# Why I can access to view from not UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, ui-thread, java-threads

I'm confused by the problem of updating UI elements from different threads.
Android allow us update views only from UI thread.
But recently I tried the following construction in onCreate() method:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mUserNameTv.setText("some text");
        }
    }).start();
```

And it works. I can't understand how it works. Please someone explain me. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928551/no-error-calling-textview-settext-from-non-ui-thread-why#comment22691658_15928551