# How to settext Textview in another Thread? (Android)

Tags: java, android, tcp

I have a TCP Client running in a Thread. Now I am getting Messages from the TCP Server. The Messages are saved as an int variable.

At the Moment I am using prinln method to see the Messages.

But I would like to Show that on the GUI. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried googling ?

Comment: use runonuithread method to access UI from thread or use handler messages to do so.

Comment: Yes I tried googling and I also tried several Solutions here on stackoverflow but didn't work yet.

Comment: Please take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40781231/4770877)

Comment: Please take a look at the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40781231/4770877)

Comment: I am testing...

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One simple way of doing this is as-

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Code here will run in UI thread
    }
});
```

for more info see this 
[Android basics: running code in the UI thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread)

Comment: Where to use? It works in my TCP run() but not ouside of it..

Comment: you can write above code inside run() method. Post you code so that i can explain better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `runOnUiThread` and call `setText` inside.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
               public void run() {
                   a.setText("text");
         }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To update UI from thread .

1. you can use **runOnUiThread** as DAVIDBALAS1 told you
2. also you can use **handler** as Vikash Kumar Verma told you  you can also send data by useing **sendMessage()**  to handle like

   ```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

           final Message msg = new Message();
           final Bundle b = new Bundle();
           b.putInt("KEY", value);
           msg.setData(b);
           handler.sendMessage(msg);    
       }
   ).start();




   // Handle Message in handleMessage method of your controller (e.g. on UI      thread)
   handler = new Handler() { 
       @Override
       public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           Bundle b = msg.getData();
           Integer value = b.getInt("KEY");

           textView.setText(""+value );
       }
   };
   ```
3. you can use **asynctask** like

   private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask {

   ```
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           try {

          //Perform long running task here and 
               Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               Thread.interrupted();
           }
       }
       return "Executed";
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

       //here you can update UI this work on UI thread
       TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
       txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
       // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
       // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {}

   @Override
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
   ```

   }
4. you can also use **BroadcastReceiver**  to update UI (mostly used in service to update UI from service)
   As explain by my this friend - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14648933/4741746