# Android：why setText can work on the work Thread

Tags: android

I found that `setText` can work on the work thread on high version SDK.
Why is this code not crashing on high version SDK?

```
final TextView mTestTv = findViewById(R.id.ratio);
mTestTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mTestTv.setText("test");
            }
        }).start();

    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to textView.setText from Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049882/how-to-textview-settext-from-thread)

Comment: it's random, if you put this line mTestTv.setText("test"); inside for cycle - it 100% generate an error

Comment: I don't think it is a problem. It is just a non-documented feature

Comment: I wonder why it works on the work Thread.It is very confusing to me.

Comment: @L.q did you find an answer to this query? I have the same question...

Comment: Ya even I have same question

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
 mTestTv.setText("test");
            }
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Doesnt answer the question. Question is about why is setText working from  background thread. (IT IS WORKING FOR ME TOO)