# Android - threads problem (random characters switching in button until button is clicked)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to make random characters switching in button until you press stop button. When you pres stop button random character will be displayed as button text. The only way i manage to do it is by using Threads. But i have problem, 3-4 times it work, but when i open activity third or somethimes fourth time app crash's. I have no idea why is this happening. I need help to solve this problem. If someone know some way to do this without threads and want to help i will appreciate it.

Here is picture of app: [CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBLjL.png)

```
public class NajduzaRec extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int brojac = 0;
    String randomLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    //char[] randomLetters = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'Z', 'Ž', 'Č', 'Ć', 'Đ', 'Š'};
    private boolean threadRunning=true;
    Random r = new Random();

    private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    EditText unosReciTxt;
    Button stopBtn, slovo1Btn,slovo2Btn,slovo3Btn,slovo4Btn,slovo5Btn,slovo6Btn,slovo7Btn,slovo8Btn,slovo9Btn,slovo10Btn,slovo11Btn,slovo12Btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_najduza_rec);

        stopBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        slovo1Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo1Btn);
        slovo2Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo2Btn);
        slovo3Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo3Btn);
        slovo4Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo4Btn);
        slovo5Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo5Btn);
        slovo6Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo6Btn);
        slovo7Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo7Btn);
        slovo8Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo8Btn);
        slovo9Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo9Btn);
        slovo10Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo10Btn);
        slovo11Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo11Btn);
        slovo12Btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slovo12Btn);

        unosReciTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.unosReciTxt);
        /*while(brojac==0) {
            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
            slovo1Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
        }*/

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                while (threadRunning) {
                    char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                    slovo1Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public void stopOnClick (View v){
        switch (brojac){
            case 0:
                threadRunning = false;
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!threadRunning) {
                        char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                        slovo2Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                    }
                }
            });
                t.start();
               brojac++;
                break;
            case 1: threadRunning = true;
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo3Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t1.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 2: threadRunning = false;
                Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo4Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t2.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 3: threadRunning = true;
                Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo5Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t3.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 4: threadRunning = false;
                Thread t4 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo6Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t4.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 5: threadRunning = true;
                Thread t5 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo7Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t5.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 6: threadRunning = false;
                Thread t6 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo8Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t6.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 7: threadRunning = true;
                Thread t7 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo9Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t7.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 8: threadRunning = false;
                Thread t8 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo10Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t8.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 9: threadRunning = true;
                Thread t9 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo11Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t9.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 10: threadRunning = false;
                Thread t10 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        while (!threadRunning) {
                            char randomChar = randomLetters.charAt(r.nextInt(randomLetters.length()));
                            slovo12Btn.setText("" + randomChar);
                        }
                    }
                });
                t10.start();
                brojac++;
                break;
            case 11: threadRunning = true;
                brojac++;
                stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
                unosReciTxt.setText(""+slovo1Btn.getText().toString()+""+slovo2Btn.getText().toString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) object to update UI elements from another thread.

See this question for an example
[How to textView.setText from Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049882/how-to-textview-settext-from-thread)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see your error log.
By reading the code i'd say your problem is that you're trying to update UI items from a thread that is not the UI-thread.

To quickly test and solve your problem just put your button.setText in a runUIThread block.
To communicate with the UI-thread from another thread you can use a Handler.

DOCS:
https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)